# Why is this stock's chart so special?

Tags: stocks

I am learning about the stock market. I found a special chart for a stock ZOM. Why it is so special? It is the result of AI traders?

[image]

Comment: What about it are you thinking makes it special?

Comment: It closed at 1.60 the previous day, gapped down at the open, and climbed back up during the day. A daily trading range of 6% isn't unusual for many stocks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a penny stock, so it's always subject to "pump-and-dump" schemes, which is why many investors avoid these kinds of stocks.  The company has no revenues, heavy losses, and just announced it's increasing the size of its float (issued shares) by about 7 times in order to raise more money.

It looks to me like investors who bought in on some rumors about the company are cashing out.  But your chart doesn't show the timeframe of the chart data - is this a day, a week, a month, 6 months?

Comment: it is a 1D 1m chart